# Excel add up values in one cell based on mutliple results from one look up value

Tags: vba, excel

hope you are all doing well today! I've been working on a spreadsheet that tracks invoices and the hours recorded for each one. Each invoice has multiple entries with different numbers of hours for each entry, all with the same reference number which combines the project number and the invoice number. For example, for Invoice #1 of project CZ23, the reference number would be CZ23-1. Invoice 2 would be CZ23-2, and so on. This is located in Column I, while the hours are located in Column H in a sheet named "Document Data".

Now I have another sheet that tracks the hours called "Summary". What I want to do is have cell B28 of "Summary" add up all the hours from CZ23-1 from "Document Data". Since I barely know any VBA, I don't have code but I'll display the situation here:

[image: reference]

In this case, cell B28 on "Summary" would be 15 (all the CZ23-1 hours added up: 2+5+1+7), while B29 would be 7 (all the CZ23-2 hours added up: 4+3) and so on. It doesn't necessarily have to be B28/B29, but just as a reference I've used those cells. Thank you so much for your time - hope I was able to explain everything well.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you only looking for a VBA solution? This could easily be done with a pivot table.

Comment: Any solution works for me :) Could you explain how I could go about doing this using a pivot table? It has to be able to adapt to any new entries (since I will be adding more entries down the line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this would be to create a pivot table.

**1.** Select a cell inside your data and then on the insert tab select pivotTable.

**2.** A "Create PivotTable" box will pop-up. Verify that your data is captured in the Table/Range. Also, you can choose if you want to have the table appear on a new sheet or the existing sheet.
[image]

**3A.** In the "PivotTable Fields" box, you can drag "Reference" to the Rows box and then drag "Hours" to the Values box. This should default to Sum and should add up all the Hours by Reference.

[image]

**3B.** Occasionally the Values box will default to Count. To change this to SUM, you can select cell B4 or B5 (See Below). Right click and select Value Field Settings. When the "Value Field Settings" box pops-up, you can select Sum on the "Summarize Values By" tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's still not quite working, I've added two more photos to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the help very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the sql concept of 'group by' on column 'Reference'
In excel you can do this by using [pivot tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-d09e4d07-8cd6-4b60-afad-8fb67418800f?CorrelationId=9ca31b14-cf5f-4d40-8730-4a03594aa50b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_Toc263767342)

You will find pivot tables in the toolbar at Insert-->Tables-->PivotTable

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you go into a bit more detail on how I would go about doing this? I haven't used pivot tables in a while so I'm a bit confused as to how I can use it in this situation.